# how to add 30 min to date values in sql so they change correctly?

Tags: mysql, datetime, datetime-format, datetimeoffset, sql-date-functions

there is a timepair table. It has columns :

```
start_pair  end_pair
08:30:00    09:15:00
```

I need to shift it by 30 min - how to do it? 8:30 becomes 9:00.

update

```
set start_pair = date(start_pair) + minute(30)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can use the DATE_ADD() function :

```
SET start_pair = DATE_ADD(start_pair, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

Comment: This will return null given there is no date element in start_pair.

Comment: In his case there is, just edit the line to match your fields/variable name.

Answer (score 0):

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec add 30 minutes(in seconds) and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time

for example

```
set @t = '08:30:00';

select @t, sec_to_time(time_to_sec(@t) + (30*60));

+----------+----------------------------------------+
| @t       | sec_to_time(time_to_sec(@t) + (30*60)) |
+----------+----------------------------------------+
| 08:30:00 | 09:00:00                               |
+----------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.